# RabbitMQ docker versioning for major and minor versions

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

RabbitMQ docker versioning for major and minor versions, shows up like this under the Tags section. So does each image is pretty much the same (i.e. using 3.8 is it the same as 3.8.11 and if they release 3.8.12 I am assuming 3.8 will be pointing to 3.8.12). So if we need to tie up rabbitmq to a certain version, should we use 3.8.11 or 3.8 in particular.

```
docker pull rabbitmq:3.8.11-alpine
docker pull rabbitmq:3.8-management-alpine
```

Comment: The 3.8.12 version is a release candidate; once that releases, there will never be updates to the 3.8.11 images, even if there's a security issue in the underlying OS image.  It's a trade-off between "I want patch fixes and security updates as long as I can get them" and "I don't necessarily trust new releases and want to validate every update".

Comment: my question is more towards whether I should pickup 3.8- or 3.8.11 or 3.8.12. Does 3.8 give me 3.8.12 by default

Comment: It gives you the current release, which is 3.8.11, not the 3.8.12-rc.1 prerelease.  This detail is on the [`rabbitmq` Docker Hub image page](https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq).